# Img-fluid class not displaying images on mobile size Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive

I have this code where I am using bootstrap for responsibility. On full screen images are working fine but when I change the width to mobile then the photos disappear.

```
<Fragment>
        <header className="jumbotron jumbotron-openness">
          <h1>{personalities.openness.title}</h1>
        </header>
        <div className="personality__body">
          <section className="personality__description">
            {personalities.openness.descr}
          </section>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <span>
                <img className="img-fluid" src={openness4} />
              </span>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <p className="personality__description">
                {personalities.openness.descr}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <section className="personality__description">
            {personalities.openness.descr}
          </section>
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <img className="img-fluid" src={openness3} />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
              <img className="img-fluid" src={openness5} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Fragment>
```

Already tried with img-responsive but not worked.

My css code, I only have css for the first jumbotron image:

```
.jumbotron-openness {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("../../images/openness.jpeg");
  background-position: 0px -550px;
}
.jumbotron-openness h1 {
  font-size: 70px;
  color: white;
}
.personality__description {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: justify;
  padding: 2rem 0;
}
.personality__body {
  margin: 0 3rem;
}
```

Photo of my problem:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Video of my problem:
https://vimeo.com/600060275/60d835adc6

Comment: Did you try to make the images responsive? Can you post your css too?

Comment: Yes, i try to make it responsive with bootstrap. I have no css code for these images, thought it should work with only bootstrap classes. I edited it, you can see all of my css code.

Comment: Theoretically it should. Try using "img {
  max-width: 100%!important;
  height: auto!important;
}" or some media queries css

Comment: Tried this now: img { max-width: 100%!important; height: auto!important; } but it's not worked. :/

Comment: Try adding the image as a div and then changing its css properties to responsive. Correct me if im wrong but i think you added the image in your css as background right?

Comment: The first image (jumbotron) is background yeah but other ones are just normal html element images. I made a little video about the responsibility, take a look: https://vimeo.com/600060275/60d835adc6

Comment: okey now it makes sense. The "header" is just fixed on top and changing vievpoint to mobile creates the expansion of the div making unnecessary whitespace. The other images have a set width and length and when the vievpoint is being changed the photos dont have the space avalible to render so they disappear. Its normal for the images. What is needed do is make the "not-header" images responsive and fix the height of the div on the top so it wont expand with the vievpoint. can you mabye send me the link to the site so i can check the properties of it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236882/discussion-between-dev-and-phaki).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with changing styles of jumbotron-openness class:

```
.jumbotron-openness {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 400px;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: url("../../images/openness.jpeg");
  background-position: -100px -600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

img-fluid is nothing more then:

```
.img-fluid{
    
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;

 }
```